# How to convert data type from CSV before load in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to load a CSV file into DynamoDB but I can't find a way to specify the type for each column of my file.

Take the following data from my CSV file:

```
"discarded","query","uuid","range_key"
false,"How can I help you?","h094dfd9e-a604-4187-99ff--mmxk","log#en#MISMATCH#2021-04-30T12:00:00.000Z"
```

The `discarded` column should be considered as a `BOOL` but DynamoDB imports it as a `String`.

Is there any way I can specify a type before importing the CSV or should I process the data with a script to handles the conversions myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS does not currently provide any tools to simplify this kind of operation rather than the REST API.

However, [Dynobase](https://dynobase.dev/), a third-party application developed to easily manage DynamoDB, allows you to import/export data in CSV and JSON formats.

The import tool allows you to select the type of data before insertion.